# Make Email Header Stay Together Across Multiple Clients

Tags: html, html-email

I have an email header that's segmented into different images so that they can each link to a webpage.

I can't seem to code the header so that it stays together across most email clients when adding the below code to mailchimp.

Here is what the finished product should look like:
http://i61.photobucket.com/albums/h49/Rocket_Range_77/Demo-header-full_zpswkpyuqa6.png

Here is the code I've been working on without luck:

```
<a href="https://espn.com">
<img src="http://i61.photobucket.com/albums/h49/Rocket_Range_77/Demo-
header_01_zpsnfqldsnw.jpg" alt="Company Logo" href="http://espn.com" 
align="left"/>
</a>

<a href="https://comcast.net">
<img src="http://i61.photobucket.com/albums/h49/Rocket_Range_77/Demo-
header_02_zps8f6i1fvw.jpg" alt="Product Image" href="https://comcast.net" 
align="left"/>
</a>

<a href="https://cnn.com">
<img src="http://i61.photobucket.com/albums/h49/Rocket_Range_77/Demo-
header_03_zpsdk8geogp.jpg" alt="Shop" href="https://cnn.com" align="left"/>
</a>

<a href="https://apple.com">
<img src="http://i61.photobucket.com/albums/h49/Rocket_Range_77/Demo-
header_04_zpsirg8szkp.jpg" alt="Customer Service" href="https://apple.com" 
align="left"/>
</a>

<a href="https://amazon.com">
<img src="http://i61.photobucket.com/albums/h49/Rocket_Range_77/Demo-
header_05_zpssvi0qteo.jpg" alt="Products" href="https://amazon.com" 
align="left"/>
</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you are after. You should use tables to place the images in the right place. Look at the table structure and you will see what I have done.

- Your code had hrefs on the image tags which i have removed.
- Dont forget display block on images and
- All links to open in new window

Below is a code, give it a try and let me know if it works for you.

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>

<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><a href="https://espn.com" target="_blank">
<img src="http://i61.photobucket.com/albums/h49/Rocket_Range_77/Demo-
header_01_zpsnfqldsnw.jpg" alt="Company Logo" style="display:block;" />
</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><a href="https://cnn.com" target="_blank">
<img src="http://i61.photobucket.com/albums/h49/Rocket_Range_77/Demo-
header_03_zpsdk8geogp.jpg" alt="Shop" style="display:block;" />
</a></td>
<td><a href="https://apple.com" target="_blank">
<img src="http://i61.photobucket.com/albums/h49/Rocket_Range_77/Demo-
header_04_zpsirg8szkp.jpg" alt="Customer Service" style="display:block;" />
</a></td>
<td><a href="https://amazon.com" target="_blank">
<img src="http://i61.photobucket.com/albums/h49/Rocket_Range_77/Demo-
header_05_zpssvi0qteo.jpg" alt="Products" style="display:block;" />
</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
<td width="148"><a href="https://comcast.net" target="_blank">
<img src="http://i61.photobucket.com/albums/h49/Rocket_Range_77/Demo-
header_02_zps8f6i1fvw.jpg" alt="Product Image" style="display:block;" />
</a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Also i take it the images on the code is just for Stack Overflow? Sending emails with images linked to photo bucket will cause delivery issues.

Cheers

Comment: What do your recommend for linked images instead of photobucket?

Comment: Good to hear it worked, accept the answer if its what you were after (and an upvote would be nice lol) for image hosting its good to have images hosted from your domain or a  reputable CDN. People usually go with the first one.

Comment: Sounds great! Unfortunately my score is too low to boost yours!

Comment: share the lov3 :-)

Comment: One comment... In order to use with mailchimp, I need  insert class="mcnImage" into the img tag, however I'm still getting getting space between the images in outlook... any thoughts?

Comment: There is a div that is placed under your image. The fix is to add 'div {display:block !Important;} or check out this tweet:  https://twitter.com/syfer_darknight/status/851737179219009536

Comment: Actually I added id="OWATemporaryImageDivContainer1" for each image per the article you sent and it seems to work.

Comment: Perfect. One up on that would do but usually that  should have been another question. Since it worked th n all good. Cheers

Comment: One issue that I'm having is that when I have images that are 1200px, setting the table width at 600px doesn't seem to make a difference, it still shows at 1200px. Thoughts?

Comment: Give the image a width. The style will have width 100% and max width of the image size.